# Angularfire remove items by checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, firebase, angularfire, removeall

I am using Angularfire and I'd like to remove the items by checkbox.

And there is a button that can do the "checkAll" and another do the "uncheckAll"

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <li ng-repeat="item in newslist">
    <input type="checkbox"> {{item.newsTitle}}
  </li>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="checkAll()">check all</button>
  <button ng-click="uncheckAll()">uncheck all</button>
  <button ng-click="newslist.$remove(item)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["firebase"]);
app.value('newsURL', 'https://XXX.firebaseio.com/XXX/');
app.factory('newsFactory', function($firebase, newsURL) {
  return $firebase(new Firebase(newsURL)).$asArray();
});
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $firebase, newsFactory) {
  $scope.newslist = newsFactory;
  $scope.checkAll = function() {

  };
  $scope.uncheckAll = function() {

  };
});
```

[plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jMx1JdMwwzrjoK8LJBIR?p=preview)

I don't know how to remove the items by checkbox or how to make the "checkAll" button work.

I will be appreciate if someone could tell me your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is function you would need to check/uncheck and for removing items:

```
$scope.checkAll = function() {
    $scope.newslist.forEach(function(el) {
        el.checked = true;
        $scope.newslist.$save(el);
    });
};

$scope.uncheckAll = function() {
    $scope.newslist.forEach(function(el) {
        el.checked = false;
        $scope.newslist.$save(el);
    });
}

$scope.remove = function() {
    $scope.newslist.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.checked) {
            $scope.newslist.$remove(item);
        }
    });
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/GsGVsGGjNwW4i1kTOuko?p=preview

I added `checked` property for ngModel directive.

HTML becomes:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in newslist">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">{{item.newsTitle}}
</li>

<button ng-click="checkAll()">check all</button>
<button ng-click="uncheckAll()">uncheck all</button>
<button ng-click="remove()">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I never thought `checked` property. It makes things become easy.

Comment: Hi, I wonder that what should I do if I want to combine button `checkAll()` and button `uncheckAll()` into a checkbox?

Comment: Thank you so so much. Actually I tried a stupid way that I wrote two checkboxes and I used `ngShow` to make one of them visible or invisible. I'm not good at using `$watch`. It's really nice of you! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, ngShow way is also smart, just you need to make sure checkAll checlbox is hidden if at least one is unchecked. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.